# ERROR - oracle.jdbc.pool.OracleDataSource

Tags: oracle, connection, oracle-adf, jdeveloper

I'm trying to develop an adf mobile app using jDeveloper and oracle sql developer.

I have connected jDev and sql. I want to populate selectOneChoice comp. that I m gonna fetch datas.

this is my connection method;

```
package salesorder.application;

import groovy.sql.Sql;

import java.sql.Connection;

import java.sql.PreparedStatement;
import java.sql.SQLException;

import javax.sql.DataSource;

import oracle.adf.share.jndi.InitialContextFactoryImpl;

import oracle.adfmf.framework.api.AdfmfJavaUtilities;

import oracle.jbo.server.InitialContextImpl;

import oracle.jdbc.connector.OracleConnectionManager;
import oracle.jdbc.pool.OracleDataSource;

public class DBConnection {
  public DBConnection() {
    super();
  }


   private static String jdbcUrl = "jdbc:oracle:thin:@10.172.105.37:1521:VIS";
   private static String userid = "***";
   private static String password = "***"; 
   protected static  Connection conn = null;

public static Connection getConnection()throws Exception{
    if (conn == null) {
                try {

                           OracleDataSource ds; ds = new OracleDataSource();
                           ds.setURL(jdbcUrl);
                           conn=ds.getConnection(userid,password);


                } catch (SQLException e) {
                    // if the error message is "out of memory",
                    // it probably means no database file is found
                    System.err.println(e.getMessage());
                }
            }
    return conn;
}
```

}

and this, my method to fetch data;

```
    private void Execute() {
    Trace.log(Utility.ApplicationLogger, Level.INFO, Customers.class, "Execute",
                      "!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!In COUNTRY Execute!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!");
    try{
        Connection conn = DBConnection.getConnection();
        customers.clear();
        conn.setAutoCommit(false);

        PreparedStatement stat= conn.prepareStatement("select cust_account_id,account_name from hz_cust_accounts_all where account_name is not null order by account_name asc"); 

        // fetching customers name
        ResultSet rs = stat.executeQuery();
        Trace.log(Utility.ApplicationLogger, Level.INFO, Customers.class, "Execute",
                             "!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!Query Executed!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!");

        while(rs.next()){
            int id = rs.getInt("CUST_ACCOUNT_ID"); // customer id
            String name = rs.getString("ACCOUNT_NAME"); // customer name
            Customer c = new Customer(id,name);
            customers.add(c);
        }
        rs.close();

        } catch (SQLException e) {
                  System.err.println(e.getMessage());
              } catch (Exception e) {
                  System.err.println(e.getMessage());
              }
    }
```

when i try to start application, an error comes up like that.
i cant use an image. so

---

**Error**

### oracle.jdbc.pool.OracleDataSource

I dont know how Im gonna solve that, i cannot figure out why . Any help ?

Comment: Change the places where you have System.err.println(e.getMessage()); to e.printStackTrace(); and post the output.It'll give us a better idea of what is happening

Comment: I have changed all System.err.println(e.getMessage()); to e.printStackTrace(); like you have said. but same thing happens :/

Comment: Post the stack trace here so we can see what happens - this isn't a cure - it's to allow us to diagnose

Comment: sorry, I couldn not understand at first. however, i have tried to view log window before. but it disappeard. now i'm trying to open and see what's going on. I will share asap.

Comment: in debug mode, it throws exception on "OracleDataSource ds; ds = new OracleDataSource();" line.

Comment: I _think_ this is a class not found exception, probably meaning that the oracle jdbc driver is not on your runtime classpath.

Comment: ok but I have already added jdbc driver to library :/ is there anything I suppose to do about that ?

Comment: Are you including it in your runtime classpath : java -cp .:/path/to/jdbc_driver.jar MyProgram

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just to clarify - are you trying to use ADF Mobile (AMX pages)?
If so then you can't connect with JDBC to a remote database from the client.
You can only connect with JDBC to the local SQLite DB on your device.
To access data from remote servers you'll need to expose this data with web services and call those.

Comment: yea I am using amx. Im gonna try ur solution, thnx.